# GET request gives 200, but function is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, get, axios

I'm performing a GET request to display document data, and although I'm receiving a 200 *and* there is data that's coming back, the function is acting like there's no data whatsoever. I'm passing in a token and I believe that it's getting passed correctly, and I'm not receiving any error messages in the console.

**Code:**

```
let _state = {isLoaded: false},
  _dmsDocs,
  // other things

// export default class and constructor are here
    
    setToken(tkn){ 
        _state.token = tkn;
        if(_state.isLoaded != true) {
            loadREST();
            _state.isLoaded = true;
        }
    }

// this is where async function getDocumentData() is

async function loadREST(){
    axios.get(`${_Something}/etc/GetAllDocs?DocNumber=00000`, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            accept: "Application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": _state.token
        }
    }).then(dms => {
        if(dms.data && dms.data.length > 0) {
            $(".docs .dms").removeClass("d-none");
            $(".docs .msg").addClass("d-none");
            _dmsDocs = dms.data;
        
            getDocumentData(); // not hit
        } else {
            $(".docs .dms").addClass("d-none");
            $(".docs .msg").removeClass("d-none").html("<h4>No Documents Found</h4>");
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

For some reason, `_dmsDocs` is coming up as "undefined" in my watch list and I'm thinking that figuring that out could be the solution that I'm looking for. Other than that, for the life of me I can't figure out why my code's not behaving as intended.

Here's what the code looks like in the debugger. You can see the `200` and the code skipping the function call.:

[image]

Here's a snippet of `_state.token`, which shows the first few digits of my token:

[image]

Comment: Why are you sending a `Content-type` header in a `GET` request? There's no content.

Comment: `dms.data` is an object, not an array, so `dms.data.length` doesn't exist.

Comment: Since there's no `dms.data.length`, `dms.data.length > 0` is not true, so it goes to the `else` block.

Comment: Use `console.log(dms.data)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, you were right about `dms.data`---I wasn't thinking about how it was displayed. If you write your response as an answer, then I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `dms.data` is in curly braces, which means it's an object, not an array. SO it probably doesn't have a `length` property. Therefore, `dms.data.length > 0` is false, so the condition `if (dms.data && dms.data.length > )` is false and it goes to the `else` block.

I don't know how to correct that since you haven't shown the actual contents of the `dms.data` object. Maybe it contains an array and you can test the length of that array instead.